# Google Analytics Goal Tracking with Regular Expression Match

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics

I am trying to track a click of 8 pages in GA goal url tracking. I have added a onclick function to the page links like below

```
<ul class="slides">
<li class="item-content"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/X1234.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Boxes'])"><img src="featured/Boxes.jpg" alt="Boxes" width="158" height="154" /></a><span class="more"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/X1234.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Boxes'])">read more</a></span></li>
<li class="item-content"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/B1234.html"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Box-Cutter'])"><img src="featured/Box-Cutter.jpg" alt="Box Cutters" width="158" height="154" /></a><span class="more"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/B1234.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Box-Cutter'])">read more</a></span></li>
<li class="item-content"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/B2289.html"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Packing-Tape'])"><img src="featured/Packing-Tape.jpg" alt="Packing Tape" width="158" height="154" /></a><span class="more"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/B2289.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Packing-Tape'])">read more</a></span></li>
<li class="item-content"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/D1256.html"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Markers'])"><img src="featured/Markers.jpg" alt="Markers" width="158" height="154" /></a><span class="more"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/product/D1256.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView','/featured/Markers'])">read more</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

And in my GA account under goals I have set it up like below

**Goal Type: Destination**

**Regular Expression: ^/featured/***

Its been more than 48 hours and I have personally clicked these pages for testing purposes but its not getting tracked.

I am thinking my regular expression might be the issue

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tested to see that a request to GA is actually being made? There's a good chance that it's not getting a chance to fire before you are taken to the target url. Do you see the pages show up in your regular pages report?  On that note.. have you considered tracking this as an event and/or custom variable instead of a page view? Because doing it this way will inflate your page views...

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes I do see the pages in my regular page reports. I will do some research on custom variables now.

Comment: well since you want to make goals, you need to at least use an event, since custom variables can't be used for creating a goal. But you *may* want to additionally pop a custom var just for the added dimensions if you want.  The only downside to this is that if you were intending to make a funnel for your goal(s), you can't do that with events; only "destination" (page view) type goals can have funnels (for some dumb reason). But based on your code, I don't think you're actually looking to have a funnel for this.

Comment: In any case, since you see the pages in your regular page reports.. 2nd question: are they *unique* to those links, or do they share the same page name with other pages on your site? e.g. can you go to `www.mysite.com/featured/Boxes` and there's an actual page there? If so, then those numbers may be from that, not your link clicks

Comment: I'm just trying to think of alts here because at face value your regex isn't quite what you think it is, but it should still match those pages in the links.  `*` will match 0 or more of the previous character or group, so your regex is technically matching for 0 or more `/` chars. But since you don't have an end of string anchor `$` it doesn't really matter what comes after that, so will technically inaccurate, it should still match those pages. `^/featured/.*` would be the more accurate version. But again, I don't think the issue is with your regex.

Comment: Thanks again, www.mysite.com/featured/Boxes does not exist I added for tagging purposes in the goal tracking but www.mysite.com/product/B1234.html exists and yes all these pages are unique product links. I am gonna try to modify the regex with the one you have suggested and see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: since you said the pages are in your regular page report, there is a "verify" link right above the "save" button in your goal setting. It doesn't show what it actually matches, but it should show you a % conversion rate based off data for the last 7 days (assuming those pages are there from the last 7 days).  Alternatively, in your pages report, the search bar above and to the right of the listing of the pages, accepts regex.  So you can put your regex in that search field to verify what pages are actually getting matched from it

Comment: Another random thought: do the pages appear in the pages report *exactly* as they are in the links? e.g. `/featured/Boxes` ? Perhaps you have a filter that alters it, e.g. adds a domain prefix, to make it show up as `www.mysite.com/featured/Boxes` (a common practice, esp when you are getting data from multiple (sub)domains). If so, then your regex won't match that

Comment: You are correct I checked with the regex in page report using advanced tab and include page matching regex with I get nothing, so 100% I am screwing up something somewhere :) Thanks again

Comment: okay, well again, `^/featured/*` or `^/featured/.*` should match a page that looks like `/featured/Boxes` so is that what the page name in your report really looks like?

Comment: if so, then.. i dunno what to say, except that you must not be entering the regex in the search or goal right. I even tested it in my own GA instance just to be 100%.